# If an inventor discovered how to build a teleportation device and used it, what laws would he have broken and could he be successfully prosecuted?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, government, social-norms, law-enforcement

Imagine a world like ours but where a temporary portal could be constructed between two different locations allowing people to simply walk between these two places with a single step.

Now imagine that this technology is first discovered by an eccentric inventor who rather than patent it, decides to have some fun. He persuades the landlords of some local pubs (he’s based near Portsmouth in the UK) to host a weekly “National Geographic Spectacular” evening where he sets up his portal and dials in various interesting places for people to look at or even briefly visit by stepping through.

What would eventually spur the Government to try to take control of his invention and would the inventor stand any reasonable chance of prosecution for any of the offences he would probably commit? Given the extraordinary nature of the device, his unwillingness to show anyone outside of the pub cliental and his claim in court that the case was preposterous nonsense (with expert evidence from professional scientists if required) and that all he was doing was creating a very clever optical illusion.

If his house was raided nothing would be found. He has no equipment, lab or workshop (at least not locally…).

Example National Geographic Spectacular week 3 At the Hero’s pub Waterlooville about 8 miles north of Portsmouth:
The inventor’s voice slowly builds to a crescendo “All the way from Zion National Park in Utah USA … I bring you … Angels Landing” a curtain opens and a few people venture through for a closer look “don’t go too far, mind the edge it’s a steep drop and MAKE SURE YOUR BACK BEFORE 11:00”.

Edit: Re legality, no serious issues initially, but think what’s bound to happen eventually. Perhaps on this night some Brits from the pub wander off and don’t get back by closing time when the portal is closed down and some American “tourists” come through the other way get chatting have a few beers and don’t make it back either. The inventor goes on holiday for a week and they’re stranded.

I suspect the National Geographic Spectacular shows would soon have the pubs packed and people with less than good intentions might take advantage and the press would take an interest. Then what about week 4 – The blue eye of Siberia?

Comment: This is an interesting idea. It looks like you've already built your world and are wanting to know how people will act based on the scenario you have constructed.

Comment: I had no idea that in the (currently) United Kingdom it was illegal to invent and build novel means of transportation.

Comment: I'm not really sure the science-based tag fits. I mean, law and science aren't directly linked in this context, especially.

Comment: Prosecution for breaking the laws of physics would be interesting in court...who has jurisdiction?

Comment: How about some law requiering licencing for public transport and in general using unproven technology on the general public.

Comment: Not an answer to your question as asked, but you should be aware of this for your story; as a practical matter, the legal perspective will be irrelevant. When a government (any government) found out about this technology, this guy would be secretly "persuaded" (offered a fortune, kidnapped and tortured, whatever means were necessary) to share the means with them in the blink of an eye. They wouldn't flinch from manufacturing fake charges of murder or bank robbery or whatever just to get this guy under their thumb so they could get their hands on a technology so ludicrously powerful.

Comment: @AlexP – LOL Not yet! But I wouldn’t be surprised… unfortunately there is a 150 character limit on question title wording so I had to cut it down to fit.

Comment: @CalM – There is merit in what you say, but I wanted to ensure this was reality based and with no magic Suggestions?

Comment: @Palarran I agree with you totally, but the Government doesn’t hold all the cards especially early on. Initially they will not believe the reports about what’s happening in Pubs in Hampshire. Later when suspicions are aroused they have to be careful because they don’t know how it works and the secret service searching his house finds nothing (his workshop is not in the UK). Other countries might be involved as far as they know.

Comment: @Palarran, that's pretty generalized.  I wonder who "they" are?  *Most* people, including most government workers, are social.  It's only governments in the hands of antisocial personalities that would do such a thing.

Comment: @Wildcard I'm describing what the national interest would dictate; any given individual's motivations become irrelevant. Corporations do this as well; the individuals running them might be perfectly normal, but the corporation as a whole tends to sociopathic behavior in the absence of external regulation. Also, the threat that such a teleportation technology poses would allow any government to internally justify taking extreme measures to secure that technology; consider the idea of such teleportation being used to conduct assassinations or espionage, or to transport an army without warning.

Comment: @Palarran, governments, like any group, consist solely of individual people.  If you have a government totally consisting of ethical and social personalities—or even one that simply has no antisocial elements *with heavy influence* —you won't get vicious and insane behavior from that government.  Saying that *all governments* behave antisocially/psychotically is just an overgeneralization which makes the solution appear further from reach.  Sort of like the "war is inevitable" crowd.  It's some form of fatalism, not an effective approach to bringing about positive change.

Comment: An interesting question is whether visitors of the show are aware that they were teleported to the destination for real and not in, e.g. some kind of “holodeck”. Unless someone runs into a guy from the destination he knows, that would be hard to tell apart. Even then, they would wait for confirmation through another independent communication channel that the other guy remembers having met, before considering that they have met for real.

Comment: It would be interesting to open like a door to the summit of mt. Everest. The hurricane that would result of connecting a high pressure with a low pressure area would also be interesting.

Comment: There are a number of surprisingly general offences, such as "possession of information likely to be useful to a terrorist"...

Comment: @Holger I would say the inventor is very honest in this respect, he tells them exactly what is going to happen – see the example at the bottom of the question. They simply won’t believe him until they walked through, then they would be convinced immediately. Going from a dark pub in southern England to a spectacular sunny precipitous mountain top in Utah would be the granddaddy of all shocks.

Comment: @Pieter Another good point. I had considered that the device might have required modest electrical input to allow for the difference in altitude between the pub and the mountain top to prevent perpetual motion issues, but hadn’t considered pressure differences. That requires more thought.

Comment: Well, as you say, the inventor might be honest, the audience may still not believe him and even going through doesn’t prove they aren’t on a holodeck like machine, which basically boils down to what the audience considers to be more plausible or easier to invent, a real teleporter or a feeling-like-reality holodeck. As said, that may change if they meet someone they know on the other side, who can remember the meeting at a later time or when they change something that has an impact on their home environment or they don’t teleport back afterwards, but go home using other means of transportation

Comment: @Holger on one level I agree with you, they might not believe they were actually in the place, but the sense of reality with tangible things like pine cones and sand stone and the wind and the resolution of the view would blow them away. Also if you read my edit to the question some of them did get stuck away from home. I think they would have been a bit angry…

Comment: @pjc50 A very good answer and no doubt when were finally convinced of the reality of the device the Government would move swiftly with this type of conviction hoping to take control of the device. Although they might find that he was a slippery customer to catch and you wouldn’t want someone with that power to hold a grudge. The crown jewels might just get stolen or worse.

Comment: Related https://youtu.be/zJt8yzR2aoY

Comment: If he does call his shows "National Geographic Spectacular", he likely to get sued by the actual National Geographic organisation.

Answer (score 19):

I can see a few laws he might be breaking, or enabling the bar patrons to break. These aren't, generally speaking, local crimes. They're crimes on foreign soil. And petty crimes that are unlikely to result in extradition, even if they find out he's doing it or behind it.

#### Illegal power

If the source power is from something that the government regulates (ie a homebrew nuclear reactor) or even from unlicensed electrical work, that'd be a problem. But since the technology exists... somewhere else... there's some question about whether the government could find out or claim jurisdiction over that technology.

#### Trespassing

The bar patrons are stepping through into somewhere else. Is that somewhere else a public space? If not, they are trespassing on someone else's private property. That's generally frowned upon by legal sorts.

#### Immigration and Customs

Did your bar patrons leave the country and enter another country? Did their destination country grant visas or have a standing arrangement that negates the need for visas? Did your patrons pass through the destination country's customs and get their passports stamped? If not, they may now face legal repercussions for having illegally entered a foreign government.

#### Souvenirs

Did any of the patrons take any local objects as "souvenirs?" Did they pay for them? If not, they're now thieves as well as illegal visitors.

They may also face fines for not declaring the souvenirs and paying applicable duties on them.

#### National Security

*Really, this is the only one that is likely to matter.* Because of the threat this technology allows, the local government may perceive the entire technology as a national security risk. I mean, if some foreign power stole this technology, why, *they could bypass our border guards, invade our banks, steal our technologies, incapacitate our leaders and military...* The risks are far too great. Better mark this as a state secret and take it and all who know about it into custody.

And then use it against our enemies.

Comment: Those infrigements did not happen in England. If is up to the remote countries to prosecute, if they deem it worthwhile. England may prosecute for bringing goods into the country without paying customs dues...

Comment: The immigration interesting to the local government is coming back through the portal. You may have a human right to enter your own nation, but border control generally takes a slightly more restricted view.

Comment: I would assume that the inventor’s behaviour would not breach generally accepted standards, no deliberate trespass or nasty behaviour. But he might well break immigration restrictions. See bottom of the question in week 3 he linked the Hero’s pub in Waterlooville England to Angels landing Zion Utah USA and let people go through for a look around. No passports or visas involved. The only people who knew what was going on were the people in the pub and possibly a few curious Americans dropping by for a pint after their lengthy climb.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if destination country requires visas or not. This inventor will essentially be smuggling people in and out of country, bypassing border inspection.

Comment: @Alexander, ah, but the people never *crossed* the borders, did they?

Comment: @Wildcard Hmm, I'm afraid in this situation the inventor would be presumed guilty until found innocent.

Comment: @Wildcard: I think you’re right—it’s as if the inventor temporarily opened a small gap in the borders between the countries. Although I’m sure the legal ruling would be that a person crossing through the portal would be departing one country and entering another, and therefore *some* border laws should necessarily apply, even though those two countries weren’t connected before or after the existence of the portal. (In a more general sense: laws are free to ignore the nature of physical reality as long as they’re agreed upon by humans.)

Comment: The borders thing is interesting. I crossed loads of national borders the other day, with no passport checks as I was in a plane 30,000 feet up at the time. I only had to present my passport when trying to leave an actual airport. So it's perfectly acceptable to cross a border if you're high enough. What is the legal precedent for crossing borders while in "hyperspace" (or whatever)?

Comment: @alexP And all of the nations *will* prosecute, asserting that a british national has violated their borders and sovereignity and demanding reparations, probably in the form of access to the portal technology.

Comment: @Grimmtheopiner The company that owned the plane you flew in had been granted permission to pass through the countries' airspace before takeoff when they filed their flight plan. This generally happens more or less automatically, but  it permission *does* have to be asked and given before takeoff. And "There is no legal precedent" just means "the ruling that this court makes will **be** the legal precedent for the next case like this"

Comment: @Shadur: *"The ruling that this court makes will be the legal precedent for the next case like this":* Most countries actually have *laws*; it there is no law governing a certain social interaction then there is no law. This "precedent" business is highly specific to the Anglo-Saxon judicial (I cannot say "legal") tradition. The rest of the world moved away from such ad-hoc decisions a very very long time ago.

Comment: @AlexP And when there is no law because something hadn't been considered possible up until the moment someone does it, the court still has to decide what to do about it, and those precedents are weighed into the legislative debate. In all likelihood in this case, however, the courts would probably rule that the fact that he technically didn't cross a border doesn't matter - he violated national sovereignity by setting foot on its territory without obtaining permission. Given the circumstances it's almost certainly going to become a diplomatic shitstorm.

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner I am pretty sure you are subject to immigration restrictions the moment you set foot on foreign ground. Otherwise one could subvert immigration and customs by jumping out of a plane with a parachute. If that loophole had ever existed, politicians would have closed it decades ago.

Answer (score 4):

I think so long as he is careful to avoid doing a few things (and assuming that nothing in the machine is illegal or controlled, such as fissile material, etc) then he should be OK, legally-speaking.

For one, I'm fairly sure that there are no laws about uncontrolled *leaving* of the country, only entering. So if you start in the pub, go somewhere foreign, and then end up in the pub it's not going to be vastly different, leagally-speaking, to hopping in your dingy in Kent, crossing into French territorial waters, crossing back again and ending up back in Kent. Of course at this point he needs to make sure he has no *extra* people, as then you'd be in the realms of people-smuggling.

If he's leaving the country on these trips he may well be breaking the law in those countries (even just on basic immigration laws) but I think that any form of extradition is very unlikely on that front. He should of course be careful to avoid teleporting anywhere that he otherwise would not be allowed to go.

There is of course an entirely different question of precisely how - upon deciding you wanted - to successfully prosecute someone in possession of a teleporter.

Comment: Yes an important part of the question. How do you prosecute under such strange circumstances.

Comment: He demonstrated the existence of a revolutionary new technology that has the potential to change the entire game and is a HUGE threat to absolutely everybody's national security. Every single country he's "visited" in this manner is going to scream blue bloody murder and *demand* to be compensated, specifically in the form of immediate extradition of the inventor -- although they'll settle for a copy of the blueprints.

Comment: Yes when they finaly believe it and if they can catch him. I would have thought that after a dozen or so shows and a lot of media interest the Government would suddenly take a serious interest. But they would have to find him first. He might well go into hiding and that would be that.

Comment: @Slarty No, it wouldn't. Because there's one rule of reality that movies like Iron Man love to ignore: *once someone demonstrates that something **can** be done, it becomes much easier for other people in the same field to figure out **how**.* And given the implications for national security, every single country with a university is going to get *really* generous with its research grants in the particle physics/quantum physics departments.

Comment: @Slarty you're also suggesting he'll *successfully* hide. Unless his portal making gear is highly portable -- and unless he can take the portal gear with him through a portal it's making -- there's a limit to how well he can hide, especially since *everyone* will be looking for him to offer "protective custody".

Comment: As I indicated in the question if his house was raided nothing would be found. He has no equipment, lab or workshop (at least not locally…) and yes the portal can be operated from either side.
But you are right I think eventually he would be caught, probably because he wanted to visit friends and family or he made a mistake somewhere. But I think he would lead the authorities on a merry dance. And he could give himself up anywhere.

Comment: @Shadur given the potential - both military and economic - that this man and his technology represents, the British government aren't going to be handing him (or his blueprints) over to anyone!

Comment: @Mattbowyer Given the potential - and the threat - that the tech represents, other nations aren't going to take 'no' for an answer gracefully.

Comment: @Shadur This character is not going to be easy to catch. After a dawn raid he escaped before the police could break down the door into his bedroom. He comes and goes when and where he wants. His workshop is in a remote cave in Mongolia, He lives all over the place shops in large European cities, Lunches in Auckland or Hong Kong and has been seen in most American states off and on (all within 5 minutes’ walk). He was last seen several months ago in Calakmul (allegedly). Where are the authorities going to raid, when and which police force will be involved?

Comment: @slarty the third time he lunches in the same place at the same time on the same weekday a sniper puts a round through his skull. He's pretty clearly an idiot with an overblown sense of invincibility just because he made one cool toy, and that will lead him to make idiot mistakes like forming a habit when literally *every agency on the planet wants him incarcerated if possible or dead if necessary.*

Comment: @SLARTY it's your story and if you really want him to be an uncatchable super genius that's your prerogative but 1) that will make a boring story and 2) kind of renders the question you're asking moot unless you were hoping for "you're right, even if they caught him the law would be helpless in the face of this genius." But again, that'd make a boring story...

Answer (score 3):

Another issue is whether or not the electromagnetic emissions of the teleportation device violate UK laws on the use of the frequency spectrum.  Certain frequencies are reserved for certain uses, like emergency services, military, telecom, and so on.  There are also regulations regarding how much power can be used while transmitting on those frequencies.  It's really quite serious.  A certain individual who shall remain nameless told her workmen to orient the satellite system to transmit to a satellite when the line of transmission was blocked by a hotel.  Thankfully her workmen told her she was stupid and refused to do it. The transmissions from a 25 foot satellite dish can kill birds in flight and damage the satellite itself.  Line of sight microwave can damage the paint on cars.  If the scientist's device interferes with telecom systems or creates EMF interference with emergency services radio, I'm sure there will be a host of laws he has violated.

There's also health considerations.  The authorities will of course want to know if the EM emissions might have a negative effect on people or animals.

The only other legal issues I can think of are unlawfully entering another country / skipping customs and trespassing, which other posters have already mentioned.

Comment: A very good point that I had not considered. I had not described how it might work as I was unclear myself, but I assumed it would have involved some sort of localised space distortion to allow one part of 3D space to touch another.

Answer (score 2):

Just using the device doesn't break any laws unless he breaks a law while using it (eg. using it to pull a bank robbery).

The only thing he could possibly be guilty of. based on your examples, is entering a nation without proper visas or other permits.  It would be up to those countries to prosecute (if there was any evidence to back up their claim).

The one with the biggest claim would be the National Graphic Institute who may sue over trademark infringement.

Of course, that doesn't mean that if the nation wanted his secrets badly enough that they couldn't just make something up.  If they call him a terrorist, they can mostly do whatever they want.

Comment: They can do whatever they want but would need to be careful. Imagine a dawn raid. 4am and the inventors door get smashed in and he hears shouts of "armed police" and people running up the stairs. When they burst into his bedroom they find that he has escaped througha portal and they are facing a dozen armed chineese soldiers across the other side of the portal.

Answer (score 2):

**Murder**

A common question amongst fans of Star Trek is exactly how a transporter operates.

One of the biggest implications is that the transporter essentially turns you into energy, sends that energy to a destination, then reassembles you.

BUT - is the reassembled you really you?  Or did the old you die, and the new you is just a copy?

They even mention in a Star Trek episode how transporting can sometimes leave "errors" in the DNA, just like how a photocopier makes a slightly poorer version of the original document.

And one interesting episode where it was discovered a second Will Riker had been accidentally created; which is the real Riker?

So it could be argued that the transporter is actually killing the original person.  This would be considered murder, even though a new version of the person is created.

It kind of depends on how the machine works.

**International Travel**

You know those trips to other countries? Do the people have valid passports? Are they getting them stamped? Are they getting the proper vaccines.

If one of those tourists gets bitten by a mosquito (without knowing it), they could bring a deadly disease home.

There's all kinds of implications you could explore there.

Comment: This idea has been explored outside of Star Trek as well.  http://existentialcomics.com/comic/1

Answer (score 2):

**Smuggling**

Your device would make it extremely easy to transport physical goods from one country to another, bypassing all examination by customs and excise officials, and thus evading paying import duty.

Consider tobacco and alcohol. In the UK, these items are heavily taxed on import, and thus there is already a significant problem with smuggling.

If the machine does what it claims, then your protagonist would be able to do things like getting crates of cigarettes shipped to an address in another country, then open his portal and carry them across undetected. It would be completely undetectable and untraceable. He wouldn't even need to steal them or break any local laws.

Whether he actually does this or not for himself, he is also running the risk of his clients doing the same thing. Everyone who goes through the portal could be carrying items that they are intending to illegally export, and could return with illegal imports. The protagonist may not even be aware of it, but he could be seen as liable in the eyes of the authorities.

If the authorities wanted to clamp down on him, it would be very easy to invent charges along these lines, and very hard for him to prove them wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**Illegal introduction of invasive species.**

At some point he opens a portal to somewhere in Alberta.

http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2003/03/0331_030331_rats_2.html

While the portal is open a few rats from the pub slip through.

**Transmissions of pathogens**

One of his nightly portals goes to a country where foot and mouth is endemic.
The bar patrons track round some local scenery and come back with contaminated material on their feet. At least one of the patrons is a farmer who's farm ends up being herd zero for a new UK foot and mouth outbreak costing the government hundreds of millions.

**Drug smuggling**

Controlled substances vary by country.

The patrons go for a wander to visit the Mada'in Saleh in Saudi Arabia but carry their pints with them. One of them is picked up by local police. They get the story about the scientist transporting them and since he helped them transport the alcohol into the country illegally he's caused an international incident.

Or perhaps the reverse and one night when he opens a portal to Afghanistan one of the bar patrons with a heroin habit takes the chance to buy some cheap heroin. He's later caught with it in the UK and the story comes out about the portal.

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly and above all he broke the laws of physics, which is inexcusable.

Comment: That was a fast downvote. I stand by my answer: He didn't break any legal law unless he did something forbidden with his device -- same as with any other device --, but he did break the laws of phsics indeed, and thoroughly.

Comment: If the inventor's teleportation device broke the laws of physics it wouldn't work. I didn't downvote. And, yes, there is no excuse for breaking the laws of physics.

Comment: Well I suppose that was a bit hasty on my part (so reversed). But I think immigration laws must have been broken and whilst you are correct concerning the laws of physics as we know them today, the laws of physics are always subject to development and new discoveries. More importantly the laws of physics were not the subject of the question.